# Submit button doesn't work in a form containing table with foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a `form` which contains a `table`. In the `table`, I used a `foreach` to fetch multiple data.

This is my code:

```
<from method="post" action="/provider/provider/checkUserCodeValidation">

<table style="direction: rtl;text-align: right;width: 1500px;font-family: tahoma;" align="center">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:5%; ">row</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Fullname</th>
    <th style="width:30%">Title</th>
    <th style="width: 5%">Number</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>ProCode</th>
    <th>UseCode</th>

  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
  $i=1;
  foreach($Items as $Item)
  {
    echo '<tr>
      <td>'.$i.'</td>
      <td>'.$Item->getUser()->getFullName().'</td>
      <td>'.$Item->getContractTitle().'</td>
      <td>'.$Item->getCount().'</td>
      <td>'.$Item->getCreationDate(true,'Date').'</td>
      <td>'.$Item->getProviderCode().'</td>
      <td><input name=userCode id=userCode></td>

    </tr>';
    $i++;
  }
  ?>
  </tbody>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit_butt" value="Submit"/>
</table>


</from>
```

The values in each row are static except the `UseCode` which is an input tag.
The user inputs a number and by pressing the `submit` button, the form should post data but it doesn't. 
I'd like to know why? Am I even allowed to do this having a foreach in table? If not, what else I should do to achieve this?

The solution in anyway helps! `JQuery`, `Ajax`, anything.

Comment: Post your JS / Jquery part too

Comment: Where is `form` tag?

Comment: @noobie-php I'm not using any JS it's a simple html and php thing

Comment: @YuvaRaj oh Dang! For some reason I forgot it! I edit it now

Comment: Can you show us the rendered code?

Comment: So why Tag js/jq if you aren't using it, nor it has anything to do with your problem?

Comment: @RenokK solving it by JS is an option if it is possible. I guess that explains the JS tags

Comment: can you share the generated html?

Comment: also how are you saying the form is not getting submitted?

Comment: Run your HTML through https://validator.w3.org/nu/ — you have at least one obvious error which could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: are you sure there are no event handlers that is preventing the form submit action

Comment: @ArunPJohny The button is not functioning! it doesn't do anything! It's in my localhost! I wish I could

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give your input element proper name.

Change

```
<td><input name=userCode id=userCode></td>
```

To:

```
<td><input name="userCode[]" id="userCode" value=""/></td>
```

Please notice the square brackets `[]` around the `name` attribute.

As you are posting multiple values, you need to post array not a single value.

In backend PHP, just use,

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST['userCode']);
echo '</pre>';
```

And you will get all posted values within loop.

**EDIT:**

`<form>` tag is incorrect.

Change:

```
<from
```

To

```
<form
```

Also, closing tag.

Comment: It is not working!
Besides, I don't get the value attribute! what does <?=$idField;?> do?

Comment: @Sean, it must work. As you are posting the form. There is no fancy code, everything simple. `$idField` is just for demo purpose, you can use your own variable.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but as you know the user has to input this value.  In your code,  <?=$idField;?> will be printed on the input fields and still nothing will happen!

Comment: I wish I could have shown it to you! it doesn't work!
I even changed the action to action="https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl" but the button doesn't do anything!!!

Comment: Holy mother of Earth! 
I feel so dumb right now! That was the problem! Thanks man! Also for your hint on the array thing! Thanks!

Comment: I should have been able to give you +100 but I do what I can! ;)

Comment: @Sean, glad to know that it worked. Congrats and Welcome.